# How to correctly set output voltage with LT3080

Tags: power-supply, resistors, voltage-regulator

I have designed the schematic below, wanting to build a simple power supply for a project. Problem is, the LT3080 is outputting around 15V no matter what R1 I use.

Trying to find the root cause, I have removed all components following the LT3080 (except for R1), but to no avail.

I am measuring 11Vac across the transformer (it is rated 7.5V @ 1.5VA) and 15Vdc across the bridge. Measuring the tab of the LT3080 gives 14.7V (same voltage if I measure across C4. All of this with a 470kO R1... which if I'm not mistaken should output 4.7V

Can anyone shed some light on this?

[image: power supply schematic]

Comment: According to a discussion on the EEVblog forum, the LT3080 has been silently upgraded to other parts by LT due to a design problem that can lead to latchup.

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but which discussion, link?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this was the thread: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/lt3080-wierdness-dave_s-power-supply-(eev224)-gone-mad/25/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal for regulators to require a minimum load before they can take effect. From the datasheet, the minimum load current for your part is 0.5mA.  If you remove everything in your circuit after the LT3080, it won't regulate.

Comment: That might be a very valid point. I will check again (while using a load).

Comment: Also, quick question: does C3 have the correct polarity in my schematic?

Comment: C3 has the correct polarity but I would test without this capacitor for now. The problems with the LT3080 I mentioned in my comment are related to the difference between the SET and OUT pins. I do suggest you read that thread.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be connecting the status led now, without any other bypass caps and see if it behaves correctly.

Comment: The main thing to avoid in your testing for now is shorts on the output. SET and OUT must remain within 0.3V per the datasheet, but with the cap the datasheet shows on the SET pin this isn't happening. You can still get the part to work for you if you understand the issues.

Comment: Just tested it. With the LED attached, it spits out 7.4V and If I remember my calculations correctly, the LED should draw only 20mA from a 5V line with the current resistor, so I assume everything should be ok in actual use

Comment: I'll go on and read that topic on he EEVblog forum now

Comment: It worked like a charm. Only strange thing (for me at least) is that it outputs 6.7V, but I only measure around 4.5V between LT3080 tab and reservoir cap top (which I remember to be ground)

Comment: If you are programming an output voltage of 4.7V using a 470k resistor, and are measuring 6.7V, then there is still a problem to solve. I take it you have tested the programming resistor and confirmed its value. As for C4, if needed it should be across the output before your load.

Comment: Your schematic doesn't show junctions. It's left to the reader to figure out which crossings are connected and which aren't. Junctions such as at the top of R1 and C3 should have a proper circular blob. This caused me to miss that C4 may actually be properly across the output.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention it was programmed for 6.7V. So in that regard, the output was correct. It just puzzled me why didn'y it measure 6.7V on the LT3080 tab as well. And yes, I did test the resistor and it measured 670kO.

Comment: My bad on the junctions. A bad habbit I developed. C4 is across the output (and both output connectors are paralleled except for the limiting resistor on the LED output)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51884/discussion-between-replete-and-catalinm).

Answer (score 1):

> - V OUT = R SET • 10µA
> - Minimum Load Current: 0.5mA

Thus Vout = 0.47M *10µ = 4.7V assuming there is an Emitter resistor on output. 
[image]

- 4.7V/0.5m=<10k max for Rload  ,
- Rmin to get 1.1a depends on heatsink Rth and \$Delta(V_{in-out})*I*R_{th}[\deg C/W]\$ for 85'Cmax